# why i set longreadlen but it did't work?

Tags: perl

```
dbi:ODBC: LongReadLen and LongTruncOk
```

I user perl DBI select some data from `Sqlserver 2008.`

```
error:
DBD::ODBC::st fetchrow_arrayref failed: st_fetch/SQLFetch (long truncated DBI attribute LongTruncOk not set and/or LongReadLen too small) (SQL-HY000)
```

when I use

```
$dbh_mssql->{LongTruncOk}   = 1;
```

it worked,but will sub the string.

i don't want the substring.  so  i try

```
$dbh_mssql->{LongTruncOk}=1;      
$dbh_mssql->{LongReadLen}    = 1048576*1024;
```

but it  also sub the string.